# How to set up yaws 1.89 in ubuntu

Tags: erlang, erl

When I am trying to install yaws 1.89, the error bellow is raised. Please help me to overcome that error.

```
~/yaws$ sudo yaws

Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)


1> =ERROR REPORT==== 14-Mar-2014::15:05:09 ===
Failed to load setuid_drv (from "/usr/local/lib/yaws/priv/lib") : "Driver compiled with incorrect version of erl_driver.h"
=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Mar-2014::15:05:09 ===
FATAL {'EXIT',normal}


=INFO REPORT==== 14-Mar-2014::15:05:09 ===
    application: yaws
    exited: {{shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,yaws_server,
                     {badconf,
                         [{yaws_server,init,1,
                              [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,159}]},
                          {gen_server,init_it,6,
                              [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                              [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}},
             {yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,yaws,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,yaws_server,{badconf,[{yaws_server,init,1,[{file,\"yaws_server.erl\"},{line,159}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]}}},{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,yaws,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,yaws_server,{badconf,[{yaws_server,init,1,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,159}]},{ge
```

Comment: How did you install yaws?

Comment: when i was tryng to install it through std apt-get install yaws

Comment: i got error when i installed it in above way so i tried it in another wayi.e., wget http://yaws.hyber.org/download/yaws-1.89.tar.gz
 tar xfz yaws-1.89.tar.gz
 sudo apt-get install gcc
 cd yaws
 ./configure && make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaws 1.89 was released in September 2010, but you're trying to run it on a newer version of Erlang, R16B03, which was released in December 2013. The drivers Yaws uses, which are compiled native code, were compiled using a version of the [Erlang driver interface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/driver_entry.html) that doesn't match that of the Erlang version you're running, which is what causes the error messages you're seeing.

Your comment above hints that you were able to get it working by downloading [yaws-1.89.tar.gz](http://yaws.hyber.org/download/yaws-1.89.tar.gz) and building it yourself; if so, then yes, that's a good way to get it working with your current version of Erlang. But a better way would be to use a newer version of Yaws — the latest version at this time of writing is [Yaws 1.98](http://yaws.hyber.org/download/yaws-1.98.tar.gz), released in November 2013.

Comment: thank you .. but i have  a doubt how to install yaws 1.98 in ubuntu12.04 please reply me

Comment: WHEN IAM TRYING TO INSTALL YAWS1.98 ON UBUNTU12.04 BELOW ERRORS ARE RAISING SO PLEASE HELP ME TO OVERCOME THAT PROBLEM